# Bought Magento Extension - weird encryption worried it's malicious

Tags: encryption

I just bought an extension for Magento, once I checked the files I saw that some are encrpyted in a really weird way, never saw that before and from some of the function names and includes it looks like at some places it gets content from external files...

Anyways, i would like to be able to decode this to see if the extension does anything malicious or not. I paid $300 for it and I'm a little bit worried to put that in my shop if I don't know that the extension is clean.

The code in the encrypted files looks like this:
if (isset ($††††††††††††††††††††††->Items->Item)){if (is_array($††††††††††††††††††††††->Items->Item)){$†††††††††††††††††††††††=$††††††††††††††††††††††->Items->Item;}else {$†††††††††††††††††††††††=array ($††††††††††††††††††††††->Items->Item);}}else {return array (0,0);}self::_getExistingsProducts(chr(97).chr(109).chr(97).chr(122).chr(111).chr(110).chr(105).chr(109).chr(112).chr(111).chr(114).chr(116).chr(98).chr(111).chr(111).chr(107).chr(115));$††††††††††††††††††††††††=array ();$†††††††††††††††††††††††††=array ();foreach ($††††††††††††††††††††††† as $††††††††††††††††††††††††††=>$††††††††††††††){$†††††††††††††††††††††††††††=array (chr(97).chr(115).chr(105).chr(110)=>$††††††††††††††->ASIN,chr(115).chr(107).chr(117)=>self::_getProductSku($††††[chr(115).chr(107).chr(117)],$††††††††††††††),);if (in_array($†††††††††††††††††††††††††††[chr(97).chr(115).chr(105).chr(110)],$††††††††††††††††††††††††)|| in_array($†††††††††††††††††††††††††††[chr(115).chr(107).chr(117)],$†††††††††††††††††††††††††)|| self::_existsProduct($†††††††††††††††††††††††††††,true)){$††††††††††††††††††++ ;continue ;}try {$††††††††††††††††††††††††[]=$†††††††††††††††††††††††††††[chr(97).chr(115).chr(105).chr(110)];$†††††††††††††††††††††††††[]=$†††††††††††††††††††††††††††[chr(115).chr(107).chr(117)];$††††††††††††††††††††††††††††[]=$††††[chr(108).chr(111).chr(99).chr(97).chr(108)];$††††††††††††††††††††††††††††[]=$†††††††††††††††††††††††††††[chr(97).chr(115).chr(105).chr(110)];$††††††††††††††††††††††††††††[]=$†††††††††††††††††††††††††††[chr(115).chr(107).chr(117)];$††††††††††††††††††††††††††††[]=self::getProductCategories($††††††††††††††,true);$††††††††††††††††††††††††††††[]=isset ($††††††††††††††->ItemAttributes->Title)?$††††††††††††††->ItemAttributes->Title:$††††††††††††††->ASIN;$††††††††††††††††††††††††††††[]=self::_getImagesCount($††††††††††††††);$††††††††††††††††††††††††††††[]=$††††††††††††††->DetailPageURL;list ($†††††††††††††††††††††††††††††,$††††††††††††††††††††††††††††††,$†††††††††††††††††††††††††††††††,$††††††††††††††††††††††††††††††††,$†††††††††††††††††††††††††††††††††)=WP_Amazonimportproducts_Model_Amazonoffer::getOfferInfo($††††††††††††††,$††††[chr(100).chr(101).chr(102).chr(97).chr(117).chr(108).chr(116).chr(80).chr(114).chr(105).chr(99).chr(101)]);$††††††††††††††††††††††††††††[]=$†††††††††††††††††††††††††††††;$††††††††††††††††††††††††††††[]=floatval($††††[chr(100).chr(101).chr(102).chr(97).chr(117).chr(108).chr(116).chr(80).chr(114).chr(105).chr(99).chr(101).chr(80).chr(108).chr(117).chr(115).chr(80).chr(101).chr(114).chr(99).chr(101).chr(110).chr(116)]);$††††††††††††††††††††††††††††[]=floatval($††††[chr(100).chr(101).chr(102).chr(97).chr(117).chr(108).chr(116).chr(80).chr(114).chr(105).chr(99).chr(101).chr(80).chr(108).chr(117).chr(115).chr(85).chr(110).chr(105).chr(116)]);$††††††††††††††††††††††††††††[]=$††††††††††††††††††††††††††††††;$††††††††††††††††††††††††††††[]=$†††††††††††††††††††††††††††††††;$††††††††††††††††††††††††††††[]=$††††††††††††††††††††††††††††††††;$††††††††††††††††††††††††††††[]=$†††††††††††††††††††††††††††††††††;$††††††††††††††††††††††††††††[]=self::_getProductDetail($††††††††††††††);$††††††††††††††††††††††††††††[]=serialize($††††††††††††††);$††††††††††††††††††††††††††††[]=$††††††††††††††††††††;$††††††††††††††††††††††††††††[]=0;$††††††††††††††††††††††††††††[]=date(chr(89).chr(45).chr(109).chr(45).chr(100).chr(32).chr(72).chr(58).chr(105).chr(58).chr(115));$††††††††††††††††††††††††††††[]=$††††[chr(100).chr(101).chr(102).chr(97).chr(117).chr(108).chr(116).chr(80).chr(114).chr(105).chr(99).chr(101)];$††††††††††††††††††††††††††††[]=$††††[chr(100).chr(101).chr(102).chr(97).chr(117).chr(108).chr(116).chr(67).chr(111).chr(110).chr(100).chr(105).chr(116).chr(105).chr(111).chr(110)];$†††††††††††++ ;}catch (Exception $†††††††††††††††††){Mage::helper(chr(97).chr(109).chr(97).chr(122).chr(111).chr(110).chr(105).chr(109).chr(112).chr(111).chr(114).chr(116).chr(112).chr(114).chr(111).chr(100).chr(117).chr(99).chr(116).chr(115))->{"\x6c\x6f\x67"}($†††††††††††††††††->{"\x67\x65\x74\x4d\x65\x73\x73\x61\x67\x65"}(),chr(71).chr(101).chr(116).chr(32).chr(66).chr(111).chr(111).chr(107).chr(32).chr(73).chr(110).chr(102).chr(111).chr(32).chr(102).chr(114).chr(111).chr(109).chr(32).chr(65).chr(109).chr(97).chr(122).chr(111).chr(110).chr(32).chr(65).chr(80).chr(73).chr(44).chr(32).chr(82).chr(101).chr(115).chr(112).chr(111).chr(110).chr(115).chr(101).chr(32).chr(69).chr(114).chr(114).chr(111).chr(114),chr(105).chr(109).chr(112).chr(111).chr(114).chr(116));}}

This is only a small excerpt from one of the encrypted files, and I'm looking for a way to display the code unencoded so I can check it. Sorry for the format, I am still trying to figure out how to format huge blocks of code correctly, maybe someone is nice enough to edit it for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you will have to work with find-and-replace tools. Firstly you get the result of a php function call (`php -r "echo chr(107)"`) and then replace all occurrences of `chr(107)` to the result (`"k"`). Than replace `"\x67\x65\x74\x4d\x65\x73\x73\x61\x67\x65"` (`php -r 'echo "\x67\x65\x74\x4d\x65\x73\x73\x61\x67\x65";'`). Than replace all †-variables in methods to human-readable names.

Comment: I see, so a lot of work. Pheew :(

Thanks for the answer that was already really helpful.